# Readonly mutators with Moo

Tags: perl, moo

I'd like to have an immutable objects with modifiable fields, so that `$foo->bar()` returns the `bar` of `foo`, and `$foo->bar(42)` returns a *new* object with `bar` set to 42, leaving `$foo` intact.

Of course, I can do that with Moo[se]:

```
package Foo;
use Moo;

has bar => is => 'lazy', builder => sub { 0 };
around bar => sub {
    my ($orig, $self, $set) = @_;
    if (@_ < 3) {
        return $orig->($self);
    } else {
        return (ref $self)->new( %$self, bar => $set );
    }
};
```

But this is a bit tedious, so is there a module to add accessors with such signatures?

Comment: You could make one in the MooX:: namespace. Sounds easy enough.

Comment: Have a look at http://blogs.perl.org/users/mascip/2014/06/immutability-with-moose.html also, very interesting discussion at the end.

Comment: @simbabque a great discussion indeed.